# How to use a custom table prefix in combination with TPH in Entity Framwork Core?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, table-per-hierarchy

Disclaimer: I'm relatively unexperienced in C# / WPF / EFC

I'm working on a C# WPF application which needs to store some data in a database. To store this data i want to use Entity Framework Core. The application will uses a shared database instance which is also used by other applications. Each application has its own table prefix so my application needs to have an own table prefix as well.

*Update:*
What i want to achieve is that all objects which are inherited from `Parent` are stored in the same table. When i "load" data from the table i want an instantiated instance of conserning `Child` class. It is/should not possible to have instances of `Parrent` them self.

**Add table prefix:**

I added the table prefixes in the `OnModelCreating` function of my `DbContext` class. (This works great so far)

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).ToTable(tablePrefix + entity.GetTableName());
}
```

**Implement "Table per Hierarchy":**

After implementing the table prefix i implemented the TPH according to this description https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy
This is the implementation:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    ...
}

public class ChildA : Parent
{
    ...
}

public class ChildB : Parent
{
    ...
}

internal class EcroDbContext : DbContext
{
    private string tablePrefix = "APP_PREFIX_";

    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; } = null;

    public DbSet<ChildA> ChildA { get; set; } = null;
    public DbSet<ChildBIpp> ChildB { get; set; } = null;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string user = "xxx";
        string password = "xxx";
        string dbName = "xxx";
        string conString = "User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + password + ";Data Source=" + dbName;

        optionsBuilder.UseOracle(conString, x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable(tablePrefix + "ef_migration_history", null));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().ToTable(tablePrefix + "Jobs");

        // Add prefix to each table.
        // When i remove the foreach bellow, the TPH works fine
        foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).ToTable(tablePrefix + entity.GetTableName());
        }
    }
}
```

When i run `Add-Migration IntialMigration` i got this error: `Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Both 'ChildB' and 'ChildA' are mapped to the table 'APP_PREFIX_APP_PREFIX_APP_PREFIX_Jobs'. All the entity types in a non-TPH hierarchy (one that doesn't have a discriminator) must be mapped to different tables.`

The error says that `all entity types in a non-TPH must map a different table` but i thought i had implemented TPH for the mentioned classes. First i thought that i implementated it wrong but when i remove the table prefix part from the `OnModelCreating` part, it seems to work fine. This means that the table prefix implementation causes issues for the `TPH` implementation. How can i solve this error?

[SOLVED]
I notice that the prefix is added 3 times for the `Jobs` table. How can i solve this?

Comment: That doesn't look like TPH. TPH would have your parent table define a Discriminator and you would explicitly avoid including any TPH child tables from having `ToTable` defined.

Comment: The site you followed has nothing to do with the official documentation. The real inheritance docs [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance). What you try to do isn't Table Per Hierarchy either. TPH is the default behavior and stores all types in the same table with a discriminator column. What you want is one of the *other* types. And neither needs reflection or explicit prefixes

Comment: We can't guess what strategy you want. In both Table-per-Type and Table-per-Concrete-Type a different table is used for each type. In TPT only a type's direct properties are stored in the type's table. In TPC the inherited properties are also stored. There are benefits and drawbacks to both strategies

Comment: Why is the prefix used at all though? Is this a multitenancy question in reality? This would have nothing to do with the table strategy. In fact, in SQL Server it would be a lot easier to use separate schemas per tenant/application than try to imitate them with prefixes. You can't assign permissions to prefixes. Check the [Multi-Tenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy) docs for ways to implement different multitenancy strategies

Comment: Is `Parent` the parent of ChildA and ChildB? In that case you're using [Table-per-Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration). You can use `UseTptMappingStrategy` on the root types and let map subtypes or use `ToTable` on every type with a custom table name

Comment: The loop itself is wrong. It iterates over *all* types, including Jobs and all previously configured types. The value returned by `GetTableName` *depends* on the strategy which is still TPH, so the name you get is `APP_PREFIX_Jobs`, to which you prepend another `APP_PREFIX_`. Try to get the mapping right before trying to "speed things up"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos We are in a company environment and have no possibilities to make changes to the database server or get an own database server so we deal with the situation we have. - `Parent` is indeed the parent of `ChildA` and `ChildB`

Comment: `APP_PREFIX_` added three times, solve that by checking that `entity.GetTableName()` returns not yet prefixed table name.

Comment: @CodeNinja you didn't use the Oracle tag. Only Oracle uses `database` to refer to the server and `schema` to refer to a database. In PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server etc you can have multiple databases per server instance.  In PostgreSQL and SQL Server a schema is just a cheap subdivision inside a database.

Comment: @StevePy What i described creates an table for Parents (Jobs) with a Discriminator field. I also did not define a `ToTable` for my childs, only for the parent. Maybe this is overkilld or not needed, not sure but i will try.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the naming issue by checking if the name already contains the prefix (like @
Svyatoslav Danyliv suggested).

```
            foreach (var entity in (modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()))
            {
                if (!entity.GetTableName().Contains(tablePrefix))
                {
                    modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).ToTable(tablePrefix + entity.GetTableName());
                }
            }
```

This also solved the TPH issue for some reason. It works like a charm now.